# Why im getting argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, web

I get a TypeError whenever i run this code

```
import urllib  
import json  
serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?'  

address = input('Enter location: ')  
url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})  
print ('Retrieving', url)  
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)  
data = uh.read()  
print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters') 
try:
    js = json.loads(str(data))  
except:
    js = None  

if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':  
    print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')  
    print (data  )
placeid = js["results"][0]["place_id"]  
print ('Place ID ', placeid)

if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':  
    print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')  
    print (data  )
placeid = js["results"][0]["place_id"]  
print ('Place ID ', placeid)
```

```
Enter location: Moscow Engineering-Physics Institute
Retrieving http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?sensor=false&address=Moscow+Engineering-Physics+Institute
Retrieved 3480 characters
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-4cd76de63011> in <module>
     13 except: js = None
     14 
---> 15 if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
     16     print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
     17     print (data  )

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Hi, If my answer answered your question, you are supposed to select it has accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error mean that js is None or undefined.
Python say that js is None and so is not iterable.
Because of python when you're doing "var in something" it expects something to be iterable like a list or set.

you can test if something is None by a simple if.
It is a bit confusing but in python 0, None and False are evaluated as false by an if statement.

```
your code...
if js:
    # do your code
else:
    # js is not defined you may want to do something or not.
```

In the try-except block you specifically set js to None in case of failure.